# Determining which parameter to use based on object file?

Tags: scala

Say I have two configuration object's , each holds parameters for running a Scala program via "Test" and "prod" mode :

```
object Test = {

 param1 = "test"

}

object Prod = {

 param1 = "test"

}
```

Is there  a correct method of determining which Config should be used as part of running the program ?

One possible method though I think this is very unclean is to assign a new var to the var in question depending on some other var parameter which determines what mode running in. So :

```
object Mode = {
  val mode = "Prod"
}
```

Then when the parameter is required :

```
Object useParam = {
   var param1;

   if(Mode.mode.equals("Prod")
     param1 = Prod.param1
   else
     param1 = Test.param1
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to stick as close as reasonable to your initial code, you could let you *config* objects implement a trait with methods for all your variables and make `mode` of this config-type, like this:

```
trait Config {
  def param1: String
}
object Test extends Config {
  val param1 = "test"
}
object Prod extends Config {
  val param1 = "test"
}
object Mode {
  val mode: Config = Prod
}
object UseParam {
  Mode.mode.param1
}
```

Alternatively you can use dependency injection and inject a `Config` instance in your class in question like this:

```
class UseParam(config: Config) {
  config.param1
}
```

In that case you have to pass the right `Config` implementation (`Prod` or `Test`) when you instantiate this class.

Answer (score 0):

How about something simple:

```
// need a common base type for ProdSettings and TestSettings
// so they could be stored in the same constant
trait Settings {
  def param1: String
  def param2: Int
}
object ProdSettings extends Settings {
  val param1 = "foo"
  val param2 = 123
}
object TestSettings extends Settings {
  val param1 = "bar"
  val param2 = 456
}

// no need to wrap the attribute in `object Mode`
// as you can have top-level constants in Scala
val Mode = 'production

// don't use a var for this
val Conf = if (Mode == 'production) ProdSettings else TestSettings

println(s"param1: ${Conf.param1}")
println(s"param2: ${Conf.param2}")
```

Also, note that `var`s are generally avoided and not needed in Scala; you can always use `if` directly when defining a `val`.

However, instead of making your modules reference the configuration directly, I would pass in individual configuration items separately to keep things nice and clean.

If you still want to keep referencing entire configurations, I'd rather use implicits than dependency injection, which makes it possible to optionally pass in a configuration object to a piece of logic but fall back to the default one if none is specified:

```
implicit val Conf = if (Mode == Production) ProdSettings else TestSettings

def configConsumer(arg1: Int, arg2: Double)(implicit conf: Settings) = {
    println(arg1 * arg2 * conf.param2)
}

// globally enabled configuration used implicitly
configConsumer(1, 2.3)
// custom MockSettings
configConsumer(1, 2.3)(new Settings { val param1 = "baz"; val param2 = 789 })
```